# cannot find debugger path for <path to main.go>

Tags: goland, skaffold, delve, google-cloud-code

```
skaffold version: v1.35.1
Goland: 2021.2.4
Cloud Code: 21.11.1
```

Just create the Sample Application:

```
Go: Guestbook or Hello World
```

It builds and deploys well enough, but when setting a breakpoint it says:

```
cannot find debugger path for <path to main.go>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `Enable Go modules integration` checked in `Preferences -> Go -> Go Modules`?

Comment: Well spotted, that was it - let me accept an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked, also posted above response as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to ensure that you have `Enable Go modules integration` checked in `Preferences -> Go -> Go Modules`.

Answer (score 1):

This error will also happen if you have `-trimpath` set in your Run config under "Go tool arguments" even if have go Modules enabled as mentioned above.